# Minimum number of fibonacci numbers sum to k proof

Tags: algorithms, proof-explanation, fibonacci-numbers

The minimum number of fibonacci numbers needed to sum up to k can be computed with a greedy algorithm that simply loops through the fibonacci numbers from greatest (less than k) to lowest, and takes the number when it can. Subtract from k, and repeat. I am interested in proving why this is correct.

This codeforces thread has some insights: https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/60305,

I understand these specific points:

1. It's never optimal to take two adjacent fibonacci numbers since you can just use the next fibonacci number instead.
2. If you were to sum up all the non-adjacent fibonacci numbers less than fib(n) for some n, it'd still be less than fib(n).
3. Instead of repeating a fibonacci number twice, you can decompose it

However, I don't understand how everything connects together to prove why the greedy algorithm is optimal. Could someone lay out the full proof? One other essential point that I don't understand is why you couldn't, in theory, use some fibonacci number multiple times. elsantodel90's last comment addresses this, but I think I don't understand the "big picture" enough to see why it addresses it.

Comment: As related background:  Is there a proof that every integer can be expressed as the sum of (distinct) Fibonacci numbers?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork  I suspect that induction will answer both your question and the original question.  Point 2 is an interesting property of Fibonacci numbers in that summing alternate terms, ignoring the duplicated $1$, always gives one less than the next Fibonacci number (again with an inductive proof) as in $1+3+8+21=34-1$ and $2+5+13+34=55-1$ so $1+3+8+21+55=89-1$ etc. and this justifies point 1.  It also more than answers your question, since it means that all positive integers must then be the sum of non-adjacent Fibonacci numbers.

Comment: Point 3 is a little subtle, but it essentially says that if you see $2Fib_n$ then you can replace it with $Fib_{n+1}+Fib_{n-2}$.  If you use the greedy algorithm I think you should never see $2Fib_n$

Comment: Yeah I understand why these three points are true. I'm missing the big picture though, could someone explain the full steps of the proof using these three points for why the algorithm correctly returns the minimum? (and also explains why, in principle, you couldn't use some fibonacci number multiple times?)

Comment: See [Zeckendorf's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeckendorf%27s_theorem)

Comment: I saw that, but that page shows existence and uniqueness, not optimality, which doesn’t address my questions at all

Comment: "I saw that", "which doesn't address my question *at all*" is a little rude. People who attempt to help you doesn't deserve this kind of comment. Moreover, how can we guess that you know for example this information as you don't mention it in your question ?

Comment: Apologies, did not mean to come off that way. Appreciate the pointer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that Fibonacci numbers are defined by $F_1=F_2=1$, $F_{n+2}=F_n+F_{n+1}$ for $n\ge1$.

For a multiset of positive integers $M$, let $\ell(M)$ be the number of integers in $M$, $s(M)$ be the sum of integers in $M$ and $p(M)$ be the sum of the squares of integers in $M$.  Note that $p(M)\le s(M)^2$. Call a multiset of Fibonacci numbers $M$ a $k$-set if the $s(M)=k$. Let $g(k)$ be the multiset of Fibonacci numbers found by the greedy algorithm on $k\ge1$ that chooses the largest possible Fibonacci number at each stage.

The question is how we can prove the following claim.
**Claim**: Let $M$ be a $k$-set. Then $\ell(M)\ge\ell(g(k))$.

#### A rigorous proof

The basic ideas have been stated in the question.

Repeat the following operations on $M$ as long as one of the operations is possible.

- If there are two $1$'s in $M$, replace them with a $2$.
  We can verify that $\ell(M)$ is reduced by $1$, $s(M)$ is not changed and $p(M)$ is increased by $2\ge2$ by this operation.
- If there are two $F_n$'s in $M$ for some $n\ge3$, replace them with $F_{n+1}$ and $F_{n-2}$.
  We can verify that $\ell(M)$ is not changed, $s(M)$ is not changed while $p(M)$ is increased by $2{F_{n-1}}^2\ge2$ by this operation.
- If there are $F_n$ and $F_{n+1}$ in $M$ for some $n\ge1$, replace them with $F_{n+2}$.
  We can verify that $\ell(M)$ is reduced by $1$, $s(M)$ is not changed while $p(M)$ is increased by $2F_nF_{n+1}\ge2$ by this operation.

In summary, each operation will not increase $\ell(M)$, will not change $s(M)$ and will increase $p(M)$ by at least $2$.

Since $s(M)$ never changes, it is always equal to $k$. Since the numbers added by each operation are Fibonacci numbers, $M$ is always a $k$-set.

Since $p(M)$ is bounded by the constant $s(M)^2=k^2$, there cannot be more than $k^2/2$ operations. So the operations on $M$ will end.

At the end of all operations, $M$ is a $k$-set with neither equal numbers nor adjacent Fibonacci numbers, which is none other than the multiset of Fibonacci numbers in the [Zeckendorf representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeckendorf%27s_theorem) of $k$, which is known to be $g(k)$. Since $\ell(M)$ is not increased by each operation, we have proved the claim.

#### Zeckendorf representation can be found by the greedy algorithm

In order to make this answer a bit more self-contained, here are the main ideas for a proof of the known fact that the numbers in the Zeckendorf representation of $k$ are the numbers in $g(k)$.

Suppose $k=\sum _{{i=1}}^{j}F_{{c_{i}}}\ge3$, where $c_i\ge2$, with $c_{i + 1} > c_i + 1$. Given $k$, the greedy algorithm will choose $F_{c_j}$ first since $F_{c_j+1}$ $=F_{c_j}+F_{c_j-2}+ F_{c_j-4}+$ $\cdots+$ $F_{c_j\%2+2}+1$ $\ge k+1$ $>k$ and $F_{c_j}\le k$.

Given $k\ge3$, suppose the greedy algorithm will choose $F_t$ for some $t\ge3$. Since the greedy algorithm will not choose $F_{t+1}$, we know $k<F_{t+1}$. Hence $k-F_t<F_{t-1}$.

#### Some remarks

> Why you couldn't, in theory, use some Fibonacci number multiple times?

You can, in fact. For example, $16=8+8$. The greedy algorithm will find $16=13+3$. Both sum use two Fibonacci numbers. In other words, although the numbers found by the greedy algorithm given $k$, in which there are no duplicate numbers will always be as few as possible, there could be other $k$-sets with duplicate numbers that have the same cardinality.

On the other hand, there cannot not be three equal Fibonacci numbers in an optimal sum. $F_n+F_n+F_n=F_{n+2}+F_{n-2}$ for $n\ge3$.